# adb app will not start

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I install Android SDK Platform-tools with the SDK manager app. The adb app in platform-tools will not work.

> platform-tools/adb: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I want to change the default installation path on my android with the command:
*adb shell pm set-install-location 2*

It used to work. I use Fedora 23.

Comment: can you please put your terminal image with commands that you fired

Comment: @SilvansSolanki  i just used cd to go to the directory and then used ./adb. If it can help i can make a screenshot.

Comment: i think adb is not executable so do not use ./adb instead of it use only adb

Comment: @SilvansSolanki it says command not found

Comment: You are probably running the binary on an unsupported arch. http://askubuntu.com/questions/648555/bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error